# Subsonic Add or Update methods conversion to Generic Method

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, subsonic3

So I've got these two methods

```
private static void AddOrUpdate(Computer input)
{
    if (Simple.Repository.Exists<Computer>(o => o.ObjectSid == input.ObjectSid))
    {
        Simple.Repository.Update(input);
    }
    else
    {
        Simple.Repository.Add(input);
    }
}

private static void AddOrUpdate(User input)
{
    if (Simple.Repository.Exists<User>(o => o.ObjectSid == input.ObjectSid))
    {
        Simple.Repository.Update(input);
    }
    else
    {
        Simple.Repository.Add(input);
    }
}
```

and as an exercise I'm wondering if I could use a generic method but just changing the method to

```
private static void AddOrUpdate<T>(T input)
    {
        if (Simple.Repository.Exists<T>(o => o.ObjectSid == input.ObjectSid))
        {
            Simple.Repository.Update(input);
        }
        else
        {
            Simple.Repository.Add(input);
        }
    }
```

doesn't work - the compiler says that type T must be a reference type.

So is it possible? Or even desirable? Is there a better refactoring?

```
    public class User
    {
        private string _samAccountName;

        [DisplayName("User Name")]
        public string SamAccountName 
        {
            get { return _samAccountName ?? "No User"; }
            set { _samAccountName = value; } 
        }

        public string UserPrincipalName { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastLogonTimeStamp { get; set; }
        [SubSonicPrimaryKey] public Guid ObjectSid { get; set; }
        public Guid? ComputerGuid { get; set; }
    }

and

    public class Computer
    {
        public string DistinguishedName { get; set;}
        public string DnsHostname { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Cn { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastLogonTimeStamp { get; set; }
        public String OperatingSystem { get; set; }
        public string OperatingSystemServicePack { get; set; }
        [SubSonicPrimaryKey] public Guid ObjectSid { get; set;}
        public Guid? UserGuid { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If Computer and User inherit from a base class that defines `public Guid ObjectSid` then you can define your generic method as

```
private static void AddOrUpdate<T>(T input) where T : BaseClass, new()
{
    if (Simple.Repository.Exists<T>(o => o.ObjectSid == input.ObjectSid))
    {
        Simple.Repository.Update(input);
    }
    else
    {
        Simple.Repository.Add(input);
    }
}
```

and away you go.

Answer (score 0):

We have done this by making all our SubSonic generated classes implement an interface:

```
public interface IPersistable {
  bool IsPersisted { get; }
}
```

The implementation of IsPersisted checks if the primary key field is equal to the default value for that type.  We then drive an Add or Update decision on Save off of that. This let's us avoid querying the DB to see if the id exists there or not.